# Is there a way to trigger a notification when a document is add/updated/committed in Solr 4.7

Tags: solr, solr4

I have been searching for a way to implement a hook/callback/event in Solr in order to get notified when a document is added/updated/committed.  Right now, I am thinking I might have to simply parse the logs, but it would be nice to be able to implement something as a module/plugin if it already exists.  I have looked through the JavaDoc for 4.7, but I am not seeing anything.  I saw RealTimeGet, but that seems to not be what I am looking for.

Are there any hooks available built-in to Solr, or am I going to have to roll-my-own using the logs to determine what has been changed in the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an executable on postCommit and use a timestamp field (like arun was suggesting) if need be

```
<!-- The RunExecutableListener executes an external command.
         exe  - the name of the executable to run
         dir  -  dir to use as the current working directory. default="."
         wait - the calling thread waits until the executable returns.
                default="true"
         args - the arguments to pass to the program.  default=nothing
         env  - environment variables to set.  default=nothing
      -->
    <!-- A postCommit event is fired after every commit
      -->
    <listener event="postCommit" class="solr.RunExecutableListener">
      <str name="exe">snapshooter</str>
      <str name="dir">solr/bin</str>
      <bool name="wait">true</bool>
      <!--
      <arr name="args"> <str>arg1</str> <str>arg2</str> </arr>
      <arr name="env"> <str>MYVAR=val1</str> </arr>
        -->
    </listener>
  </updateHandler>
```

See the [documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#A.22Update.22_Related_Event_Listeners)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for, only I was looking for something in the APIs, not a configuration item.  Will need to do some more research on how to use it, but I think this should foot the bill just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom update processor chain and create your own [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_10_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/UpdateRequestProcessor.html) in order to perform custom code for add/delete/commit/etc this also gives you access to the incoming request if you need it.

For additional information on the update processors and chains see their [wiki page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor). These processors can be built by extending the abstract Java class and bundling the plugin as described in the [Solr Plugins page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins#How_to_Load_Plugins), or alternatively you can write the implementation in javascript as described on the [script update processor page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach. You could define a `timestamp` field for all your docs like this:

```
<field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" />
```

This will get updated automatically by Solr whenever you add/update docs. Then you can query your collection for documents with `timestamp` in the last minute or some such interval.

Not sure if a better alternative exists though.

Comment: If @qux suggestion pans out, then I will probably go with that.  But I think this is a good alternative to polling the logs, so I'll just keep this in my back pocket.